# Is it possible to whitelist URL including all its suffixes in Gmail extension's manifest?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm developing a Google Workspace extension for Gmail which makes requests to backend API and fetches images from different CDN servers. Therefore it is not possible to include every possible URL in `urlFetchWhitelist` property of the manifest. Is it possible to add only the server's hostname and use some kind of wildcard to include all of its possible suffixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildcards are supported in `urlFetchWhitelist`, but they are limited to sub-domains.

See documentation linked below:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/workspace-manifests#allowlist_urls

Comment: Thanks for responding, but is there any other way to whitelist a server hostname with all possible suffixes?

Comment: Wildcard suffixes don't seem to be supported; the docs only make mention of prefix wildcards as sub-domains. See [Using Wildcards](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/workspace-manifests#using_wildcards)